# request specでPOSTを送信して対象のデータの数を一つ増やしたいが、Can't verify CSRF token authenticityが出てしまう

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

### 環境

- Rails7.0
- Docker

### 概要

現在『Everyday Rails　RspecによるRailsテスト入門』でRspecを学習している者です。

requestspecを使用して「Postを送信し、DBに1件対象のデータが増えることを確認する」というテストを行っているのですが、以下のエラーが出てしまいテストが失敗している状態です。

**エラー**

```
expected Project::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy#count to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0
```

いくつかデバッグを行い、エラー画面を出したところ `Can't verify CSRF token authenticity` といったRailsのCSRF対策にひっかかってしまっている状態になっていたため、おそらくこれが原因かと思われます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ユーザログイン認証にはDeviseを用いております。
ユーザー生成と対象のデータ生成（Project）はRsepcのFactoryBotを使用しております。
また、現在自分が使用しているRailsのバージョンは7.0のため、いまいちCSRF対策を通過させるための方法がよくわからないため、もしご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたらご教示いただけますと幸いです。

### 該当コード

spec/requests/projects_api_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "ProjectsApis", type: :request do
# こちらのテストは成功している
    it "1件のプロジェクトを生み出すこと" do
      user = FactoryBot.create(:user)
      FactoryBot.create(:project, name: "Sample Project")
      FactoryBot.create(:project, name: "Second Sample Project", owner: user)

      get api_projects_path, params: {
        user_email: user.email,
        user_token: user.authentication_token
      }

      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
      json = JSON.parse(response.body)
      expect(json.length).to eq 1
      project_id = json[0]["id"]

      get api_projects_path(project_id), params: {
        user_email: user.email,
        user_token: user.authentication_token
      }

      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
      json = JSON.parse(response.body)
      expect(json[0]["name"]).to eq "Second Sample Project"
    end

    # こちらのテストが失敗している
　　　　　　　　it "プロジェクトを作成できること" do
      user = FactoryBot.create(:user)
      project_attributes = FactoryBot.attributes_for(:project)

      expect {
        post api_projects_path, params: {
          user_email: user.email,
          user_token: user.authentication_token,
          project: project_attributes
        }
      }.to change(user.projects, :count).by(1)

      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end
end
```

app/controllers/application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  protected

  def set_project
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  end

  def project_owner?
    unless @project.owner == current_user
      redirect_to root_path, alert: "You don't have access to that project."
    end
  end
end
```

spec/factories/projects.rb

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :project do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "Project #{n}" }
    description { "A test project" }
    due_on { 1.week.from_now }
    association :owner

    # メモ付きのプロジェクト
    trait :with_notes do
      after(:create) { |project| create_list(:note, 5, project: project) }
    end

    # 昨日が締め切りのプロジェクト
    trait :due_yesterday do
      due_on { 1.day.ago }
    end

    # 今日が締め切りのプロジェクト
    trait :due_today do
      due_on { Date.current.in_time_zone }
    end

    # 明日が締め切りのプロジェクト
    trait :due_tomorrow do
      due_on { 1.day.from_now }
    end

    # 無効になっている
    trait :invalid do
      name { nil }
    end
  end
end
```

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user, aliases: [:owner] do
    first_name { "Aaron" }
    last_name { "Sumner" }
    sequence(:email) { |n| "tester#{n}@example.com" }
    password { "dottle-nouveau-pavilion-tights-furze" }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails 7.0 のデフォルトだと test 環境では `config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection` が `false` になっており CSRF トークンの検証がスキップされています: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/1a22ebc/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/config/environments/test.rb.tt#L33-L34

もしテスト時に CSRF トークンの検証まで行う必要が無いのであれば、この設定を確認してみてください。

テスト時に CSRF トークンの検証まで行いたい場合は、request spec では明示的にトークンを与えるようにするのが良さそうです。[`ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection#form_authenticity_token`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.3/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection.html#method-i-form_authenticity_token) を使ってトークンを自前で生成し、`authenticity_token` という名前の param として渡してあげると通るはず……です。

---

ところで、テストが失敗しているのは CSRF トークンのせいではないかもしれません。テストが失敗しているエラーメッセージはあくまで `count` が意図通り変化していないよという所であり、POST リクエストが失敗したというエラーではありません。POST リクエストが失敗しているのであれば変化の検出よりも先にそのエラーが出るはずです。

ということで、おそらく `post api_projects_path` で本当にレコードの新規作成が行われていないのではないでしょうか？　このリクエストを処理するコントローラーの実装を見直してみてください。